# Error on serializing XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Hi I am getting this error, when serializing to XML

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'XYZ.ProducerChannel[][]' to 'XYZ.ProducerChannel[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'XYZ.ProducerChannel[]' to 'XYZ.ProducerChannel[][]'
```

Can someone help me with whats going on?
Depending classes:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("CarrierAppointment", typeof(ProducerChannel[]), IsNullable=false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("DistributionChannelInfo", typeof(ProducerChannel), IsNullable=false, NestingLevel=1)]
    public ProducerChannel[][][] Producer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.producerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.producerField = value;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var producer = new InitialPurchaseOrder.ProducerChannel{DistributionChannelName = division};
        bdParty.Producer = new InitialPurchaseOrder.ProducerChannel[][][]// {{},{},{producer}};
                                    {new InitialPurchaseOrder.ProducerChannel[][]
                                        {new InitialPurchaseOrder.ProducerChannel[]{producer}}};
```

Error Line:

```
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(txLife.GetType());
```

Related XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Policy" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">

                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Annuity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                          <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="QualPlanType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                  <xs:attribute name="tc" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                          </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in `xsd.exe` I have stumbled upon a few times now, it doesn't handle arrays of arrays correctly.

If that's the case you have to modify the generated classes so that the `XmlSerializer` can work with it.
Either the attributes or the type of the `Producer` property is not correct.

If you had posted the relevant section of the XML schema I could say it for certain, but try to change the type of the `Producer` property from `ProducerChannel[][][]` to `ProducerChannel[][]`.

If you can modify the XML schema maybe [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/asmxandxml/thread/c614a576-b481-4828-a96e-e7754462b0f3) can help without the need to modify the C# classes after generating them.

Comment: @Bitmask: I don't think you posted the correct part of the XML schema...I don't see a CarrierAppointment or DistributionChannelInfo there. But since you accepted the answer, were you able to solve the problem already?

Comment: The link you posted suggested I change the schema.  Although I couldn't change the schema they way the link suggested, I changed it such that xsd.exe created a class for Carrier appt and distribution channel.  FYI: the key is if there is only one nested element, then XSD.exe creates an array.

Comment: @Bitmask: Good to know. I'm glad you solved your problem. By the way, did you try my other suggestion to change the generated classes? Any luck with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty clear. You have the property as `ProducerChannel[][]` (or `ProducerChannel[][][]`), but your XmlArrayItem attribute is trying to serialize it as `ProducerChannel[]`.

Comment: that right.. But Since I generated the XSD and the .cs file (using xsd.exe), how do I serialize it properly!

Comment: Others might disagree, but I would just change it manually in the code. That's probably the fastest way in this case.